# How to create batch of accounts by using geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, keystore

To create on account&keystore using:
`geth --datadir node1/ account new`

How to create 100 account&keystore in one time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a batch file and loop around to create new account as much as you want. Further more, you can also specify passphrase by using `--password` flag in the cmd then you dont have to be asked to input passphrase for each account.